# Trigger Azure Data Factory Pipeline using Postman

Tags: azure, postman, azure-data-factory, azure-rbac

I'm kinda lost, I'm trying to trigger a pipeline manually using the following:

POST [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelines/{pipelineName}/createRun?api-version=2018-06-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/%7BfactoryName%7D/pipelines/%7BpipelineName%7D/createRun?api-version=2018-06-01)

I use to generate an access token using the following:
[image]

But I encountered the following error:

[image]

I'm not sure if it's related but I am assigned as a Data Factory Contributor Role, I can make pipelines but I could not publish them. But token does not says it is account related so.

I'm not sure if my client id and client secret are correct, it is the same as the one used for the database same subscription but different resource group.

How can I obtain the correct access token or is this even possible?

Comment: When I've done this before in Postman, I did not use the Authorization tab, but added a Header named "Authorization" with the value "Bearer {your_token_here}"

Comment: I tried same result, for getting the token did you also use the same request?

Comment: Yes, I used the same method for getting the token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application and added `API permission` like this:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** via Postman same as you with below parameters:

```http
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/token

grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
resource: https://management.azure.com/
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I ran the same query to trigger Azure Data Factory pipeline by including above access token via Postman, I got **same error** as below:

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelines/{pipelineName}/createRun?api-version=2018-06-01
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you need to assign `Data Factory Contributor` Role to service principal/application with client ID in error response, before generating access token.

*Go to Azure Portal -> Data factories -> Your Data Factory -> Access control (IAM) -> Add role assignment*

[image]

After assigning role to service principal, generate access token again and use it to run query.

When I ran query with new access token, I got **response** successfully like below:

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelines/{pipelineName}/createRun?api-version=2018-06-01
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, make sure to assign `Data Factory Contributor` role to **service principal**(Azure AD application) to resolve the error.

Comment: this fixed it, also other than that I created a new secret and id that has the data factory permission

Comment: @Sridevi

With DataFactory Contributor role, i have this error : 

{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Entity calculus_pipeline not found",
        "target": "pipeline/calculus_pipeline /runid/9f31c0fe-5ca0-4a26-b3ac-8f0981c80689",
        "details": null
    }
}

It does not find the pipeline, but the pipeline exists. Any idea ?